# Son's science project (high powered fans)

Tags: design

My son (an aspiring inventor in the 5th grade) is aiming to design and prototype a 'levitating shelf'.  The shelf can be any size (or material), the key is that he would like to use fans to try to levitate it off the ground.  I would love some advice on what sort of fans might be needed and where to look.  Any other input on making this get off the ground (even briefly) would be much appreciated.

Comment: So - this is a 'drone' but intended to be more-or-less stationary?

Comment: Give him an idea to make it magnetically levitating... Less noise, less power, less dangerous. And easier to implement (yet pretty hard)

Comment: Brhans:  yes, it can be stationary, just need it to get off the ground a bit.

Comment: A shelf implies considerable height, so levitation requires thrust greater than load, and the problem of balance. It might be better to guide him toward something simpler such as an air-ride platform. This could be achieved with a battery powered blower and a flat('ish) board for instance. Much less chance of   accidents.

Comment: This sound more like a hovercraft than a drone. If that is of interest, look for plans on YouTube and elsewhere. Whatever the type of vehicle, the choice of fan and motor is completely dependent on the weight, dimensions and other design details. This is a question and answer site. You need to find a complete design example. You can get a few hints in comments here, but probably no answer.

Comment: You don't want everyday cooling fans, you want at least vacum cleaner parts for a hovercraft, or ducted model aircraft units for something not skirted.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a "shelf" (whatever that really means) to fully levitate will be quite hard.  There are issues that are out of reach of a 5th grader, and also you, judging from your question.  Not only is quite high thrust, and therefore power, required, but keeping the shelf stabilized and not flip over and drive itself into the ground is a advanced control system problem.

However, a hovercraft is much easier.  You can make simple ones with simple materials.  A stryrofoam cafeteria tray upside down is a good start.  You can use a single propeller blowing backwards to propel the craft forwards.  Divert about half the flow from the propeller to under the tray to keep it floating.  I've seen this done by gluing half a Styrofoam cup over a opening in the tray.  The half cup is oriented horizontally, with the open end right behind the propeller.

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be a floating platform and you'd like your son to do most of the work, then I would try to source a drone or two and attach a lightweight grid as the 'shelf'. Just check the net lift capability of the drone to make sure it'll do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that seems simple but is actually really difficult in engineering terms. The problem isn't really the force of airflow needed to raise the shelf (it's a lot, but can be done), it's  a control problem.

Think of holding a tray laden with various items on the palm of one hand, like a waiter. It's quite difficult for you to keep it stable- prevent it tipping over- but you can do it. But that is because you are a human and can use tiny muscle movements to compensate for its tendency to tip over. Without doing that, it will flip over and your crockery goes on the floor. So you need an advanced control system that continually compensates for the shelf/tray's urge to tip over.

I hate to be a wet blanket but I think this is far beyond you, or indeed anyone with considerable engineering experience in the domain of flight control systems.